# jQuery UI Autocomplete: Enter to complete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

Using [jQuery autocomplete](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete), is it possible to make it so that the first item is automatically highlighted and will be filled in when the user hits enter, *but* not when they tab out of the input (input loses focus)?

The closest I've found is [this](https://github.com/scottgonzalez/jquery-ui-extensions/blob/master/autocomplete/jquery.ui.autocomplete.selectFirst.js), but that autocompletes on lose-focus.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have a solution that works - without breaking the existing behaviour - by **extending** `$.ui.autocomplete` and **overriding** the `_suggest` method.

```
$.widget('ui.myAutocomplete', $.extend({}, $.ui.autocomplete.prototype, {
    _suggest : function(items) {
        // Call ui.autocomplete's parent method
        $.ui.autocomplete.prototype._suggest.call(this, items);

        // Find the first list item
        var item = this.menu.element.children()[0];

        // Make this item active.
        // An event is expected so a fake one is passed as a parameter.
        this.menu.activate(new jQuery.Event('null.event'), $(item));
    }
}));
```

You can now use the new sub-class `$.ui.myAutocomplete` in the same way as `$.ui.autocomplete`

```
$(function() {
    var source = [
        'test 1'
        ,'test 2'
        ,'test 3'
    ];

    $('#selector')
        .myAutocomplete({
            source : source
        });
});
```

Comment: ah, but if the menu is open and you tab away it still autocompletes because an item is active.